# One line check if String contains bannedSubstrings

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `String title` and a `List<String> bannedSubstrings`. Now I want to perform a one line check if `title` is free of those `bannedSubstrings`.

My approach:

```
if(bannedSubstrings.stream().filter(bannedSubstring -> title.contains(bannedSubstring)).isEmpty()){
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `isEmpty()` method for streams. So how would you solve the problem? Is there a one line solution?

Comment: @nikis: this way it will do extra job finding all the bad words which is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @TagirValeev agree, this was the first solution came to me at first, already posted another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want to read up on [`anyMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
if (bannedSubstrings.stream().anyMatch(title::contains)) {
    // bad words!
}
```

Inversely, there's also [`noneMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
if (bannedSubstrings.stream().noneMatch(title::contains)) {
    // no bad words :D
}
```

This isn't very efficient if `title` is a long string (but titles usually aren't supposed to be long, I suppose).

Comment: I think it's better to use `noneMatch` here.

Comment: @mkrakhin I suppose that depends on the layout of the function in general, but it's a good suggestion and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: sure. I just mentioned it, because OP checked for emptiness in his `if` :)

Comment: In my case `title`is short and the check won't take much time. But of course in order to enlarge my general knowledge about efficient algorithms I'm interested in a more efficient solution. What do you think about the regexp approach of Tagir Valeev?

Comment: Also, as `noneMatch` and `anyMatch` don't need to check whole stream, it makes sense to keep `bannedSubstrings` sorted in order of decreasing probability to occur in `title`. Alternatively, starting from some point of `bannedSubstrings` length, it would make sense, to create `parallelStream` instead of `stream`.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain the regexp approach is asymptotically better, since it should needs at most one iteration through `title` regardless of how many banned words you have, whereas my suggestion requires one iteration through `title` per banned word in the worst case (which is when the string is OK, so it's also the normal case!). So long story short, I still think my solution above is the best for any normal use case, but the regexp approach is clever and performs relatively better if you have a large (and fixed) set of banned words and a long title.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an efficient solution and you have many `bannedSubstrings`, I guess, it would be faster to join them into single regexp like this:

```
Pattern badWords = Pattern.compile(bannedSubstrings.stream().map(Pattern::quote)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (badWords.matcher(title).find()) {
   ...
}
```

This should build a prefix tree from your substrings, so scanning will be significantly faster. If performance is not the concern in your case, use other answers.

Comment: You are assuming in your solution that the bannedSubstrings don't contain characters with a special meaning with respect to regular expressions.

Comment: Yes. Well, it can be easily fixed even if it's not the case. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
if(bannedSubstrings.stream().anyMatch(title::contains)){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you've selected is pretty good, but for real performance you'd probably be better off pre-compiling the list of bad words into a regex.

```
public class BannedWordChecker {
    public final Pattern bannedWords;

    public BannedWordChecker(Collection<String> bannedWords) {
        this.bannedWords =
            Pattern.compile(
                bannedWords.stream()
                    .map(Pattern::quote)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
    }

    public boolean containsBannedWords(String string) {
        return bannedWords.matcher(string).find();
    }
}
```